# How to submit a table with dynamic rows of data via asp.net mvc or jquery?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms, submit

i'm totally noob to asp.net mvc and currently i'm writing an web app which allows user to select multiple product from a listbox and add them to a dynamic table with rows that can be added or removed.

thus i'm thinking of using jquery to add and remove the table row, thus the table row will be added via append("xxx").

but the thing is i'm not that familiar with asp.net mvc form submission, from my understanding thus far, i can retrieve the value later via form["id"] but if i were to create the table row via that method, i'm thinking it's either going to be with the same id, or i can use a running no id and a hidden input to keep track of how many products that is added.

also i probably want to hide the whole product table when all the products were removed.

p.s. kinda feel that my way is sort like a big fugly messy hack which will come back n bite me one day.

### Questions:

1. does asp.net mvc has a good way to
   handle all of this? i've read
   something about mvc tempdata.
2. and is there a better way for me to
   handle the dynamic product
   generation? to make things easier
   later for form submission in asp.net
   mvc
3. and also i found that you can
       actually submit the form via jquery
       too, is there any pros n cons
       between the two method? in terms of
       maybe performance, security,
       maintenance, etc?

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can post collections of objects; in MVC.  Here is an example: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/ASPNETWireFormatForModelBindingToArraysListsCollectionsDictionaries.aspx

Basically, you can use JQuery to create the table, but ensure the ID's of the controls reference this scheme, so for the next row to add using JQuery, ensure the controls to input the data use the next index in the list, along with the same name as the property in the underlying bound object.

When you post to the server, you can loop through this collection.

To answer the others: you can submit form via JQuery if you don't want a postback to the server (can use ASP.NET MVC to do too)... otherwise, you don't need to worry about the JQuery submit.  So that may add usability.

HTH.

Comment: @brian, thanks for the info, i'll check it out, felt lost in the sea of MVC .. :) and what's a HTH?

Comment: No problem, I did too at first, but I really like the MVC product. I don't use the collection-based approach much, but seems like a very handy feature. HTH = Hope this helps, helps save on the fingers :-)