# Posting form elements with jQuery in ASP.NET MVC not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, html, asp.net-mvc

I am using `ASP.NET MVC` and `jQuery`.

I have a textbox and an HTML table with data in, for example:

```
<form action="/Server/Test" method="post">

     <input type="text" id="ServiceAccount" />

     <table>
          <tr>
               <th>Heading 1</th>
               <th>Heading 2</th>
          </tr>
          <tr>
               <td>Cell data 1</td>
               <td>Cell data 2</td>
          </tr>
     </table>

</form>
```

The table above is not bound to a view model, it gets populated via AJAX/JSON.

I need the value of the textbox and the cell data to be posted to my controller's action method.  So if I typed in 1234567 in the textbox then I need this value posted to the action method together with the contents of the table.  I need the table data also for processing.  Is this possible?  I can't find a sample.

My action method looks like this:

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string[] data)
{
     // Use the value Cell data 1
     // Use the value Cell data 2

     return View();
}
```

Given my code below it is not hitting my action method:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
     $.post('@Url.Action("Test", "Server")', $('form').serialize(), function (data) {
          alert('success');
     });
     return false;
});
```

I'm not understanding what I am doing wrong.

Comment: What does your route config look like?

Comment: It just has the default configuration as when you start the MVC project.

Comment: There is either a javascript error or its a routing issue.  If you open the debug console in your browser, do you see any JS errors ?  Ifyou open the network tab, are you getting a 404 ?

Comment: You also need a name attribute on your input field and to set the name of the parameter of your action method to the same name.  Change the type to a string from a string array.

Comment: You can't add a name attribute to a table.

Answer (score 0):

`I need the value of the textbox and the cell data to be posted to my controller's action method. So if I typed in 1234567 in the textbox then I need this value posted to the action method together with the contents of the table. I need the table data also for processing. Is this possible? I can't find a sample.`

Yes, it's possible, but your table must contain hidden inputs, `tr` and `td` data can't be sended with submit (normal submit, not ajax), also `serialize()` do not serialize table rows. Look at this question:

[How to submit a table with dynamic rows of data via asp.net mvc or jquery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2551830/how-to-submit-a-table-with-dynamic-rows-of-data-via-asp-net-mvc-or-jquery)

Comment: Thanks. I had a look at the code and it mentions input types. How does this relate to tables? Have you got some sample working code for me please?

Comment: @BrendanVogt As you wrote, you want to submit table content, just add hidden inputs with same data in `td` tags with jquery. The main idea is to create correct names, which will be binded on server side. How it could be done, you can see in article from my link.

Answer (score 0):

Basically when you submit the form, **Only form elements like INPUT, Hidden, TextAra are submitted**, NOT div, table, span, etc.

So use hidden fields for the table data if you want to submit.

Or better way is loop the table data, prepare JSON and post it as a parameter.

```
$('form').submit(function () {

     var myPostData=//construct this from table and convert as JSON
     $.post('@Url.Action("Test", "Server")', {data:myPostData}, function (resp) {
          alert('success');
     });
     return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Set `WebMethod` in your controler action methode 
for

```
[WebMethod]
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Test(string[] data)
{
     // Use the value Cell data 1
     // Use the value Cell data 2

     return View();
}
```